# Trying to understand how to combine rx.net with existing MVVM project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I currently have a WPF project that makes use of MVVM. In my project, I make use of a static class which acts as a cache for collections used by the various controls in my app, something like this:

```
public static class AppCache
{

    public static ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    private static async void GetMyObjectsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => GetMyObjects());

        Mediator.Instance.NotifyColleagues("MyObjectsUpdatedMessage", true); // A helper class that implements messaging
    }

    private static GetMyObjects()
    {

        // Get objects via service call

        ...

        MyObjects = result;
    }

    static AppCache()
    {
        MyObjects = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

        GetMyObjectsAsync();
    }

}
```

I then subscribe to the mediator in my various viewmodels:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    ...

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects
    {
        // My ViewModelBase lets me implement INotifyPropertyChanged like this
        get { return GetValue(() => MyObjects); } 
        set { SetValue(() => MyObjects, value); }
    }

    [Message("MyObjectsUpdatedMessage")]
    private void OnMyObjectSourceUpdated(bool c)
    {
        MyObjects = AppCache.MyObjects;
    }

    public MyViewModel ()
    {
        Mediator.Instance.RegisterHandler<bool>("MyObjectsUpdatedMessage", OnMyObjectSourceUpdated);
    }

}
```

The problem I have with this method is that when I do things with the collections in the ViewModels (eg. add or edit a `MyObject`) I then have to go back and manually update the global AppCache collection and make sure it matches up with what is in the ViewModel, then make sure that I update all of the other ViewModels using this collection to use the new value since there is no binding involved: `MyOtherViewModel.MyObjects = AppCache.MyObjects`

The alternative is to make `GetMyObjectsAsync()` public and have the AppCache update itself from the database after I make changes from my ViewModel, then use the Mediator to update all the other views using the collection. I don't like this either as it means I end up making a service call I don't want to.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is any way to use Reactive Extensions to simplify my process, such that I can have some kind of Reactive Property defined in the AppCache which my ViewModels subscribe to, and which when updated will push its updates out to all the ViewModels, something of a mix between the two options available to me (Manually update the AppShared collection but then have all its subs notified without needing the mediator).

I suppose really what I want is to have a property that is essentially bindable and shareable between ViewModels.

Is there any kind of Reactive Property I can use to achieve this sort of thing? Something like:

EDIT:

I was able to get the subscription to work as follows, but this is again similar to the option of using the Mediator as I have to call `NotifyMyObjectChanged` whenever I update MyObjects. Is there a way to make `MyObjectsObservable` 'listen' for changes to MyObjects and automatically call `NotifyMyObjectChanged`? If there isn't a way to do this, is there a benefit to using RX for this over the Mediator?

```
public static class AppCache
{

    public static ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    public static IObservable<ObservableCollection<MyObject>> MyObjectsObservable => _mySubject; // C# 6 syntax

    public static Subject<ObservableCollection<MyObject>> _mySubject { get; set; }

    private static async void GetMyObjectsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => GetMyObjects());

        NotifyMyObjectChanged() // this basically just replaces the mediator
    }

    private static GetMyObjects()
    {                   
        ...         
        MyObjects = result;
    }

    private static void NotifyMyObjectChanged()
    {
        _mySubject.OnNext(MyObjects);
    }   

    static AppCache()
    {
        _mySubject = new Subject<ObservableCollection<MyObject>>();

        GetMyObjectsAsync();
    }    

}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{   

    ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects 
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => MyObjects); }
        set { SetValue(() => MyObjects, value); }
    }


    IDisposable _subscription { get; }

    MyViewModel()
    {
        _subscription = AppCache.MyObjectsObservable.Subscribe (HandleMyObjectChanged);
    }

    private void HandleMyObjectChanged(ObservableCollection<MyObject> myObjects)
    {
        MyObjects = myObjects;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO this is a good use of RX, but your question is very broad and so is probably not good for a SO post.

Comment: Sorry I will try to make my question a bit more specific

Comment: Also consider http://reactiveui.net/ a MVVM framework built on top of system.reactive

Comment: Thanks I saw that but wanted to look at the basic rx framework first. Is this something rxui can help with?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is something like this:

```
public static class AppCache
{
    static AppCache()
    {
         _mySubject = new Subject<MyObject>();
    }

    private static void NotifyMyObjectChanged(MyObject object)
    {
        _mySubject.OnNext(object);
    }

    public static IObservable<MyObject> MyObjectsObservable 
    { 
        get { return _mySubject; }
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{            
     MyViewModel()
     {
          _subscription = AppCache.MyObjectsObservable.
              .Where(x => x == value)
              .Subscribe (HandleMyObjectChanged);
     }

     private void HandleMyObjectChanged(MyObject object)
     {
        ... do work here ....
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         _subscription.Dispose();
     }
}
```

In this case what you're basically doing here is sending a notification to your view model that something on your `MyObject` has changed.  You can take the `object` variable from the handler and use that to copy the changed properties into your view model.  Alternatively you could send a "message" class that has a list of properties and their new values, that might be a little lighter than sending the entire object.

The other thing to keep in mind is that the Observable might send the "event" on a thread other than the UI thread.  There's a [`Subscribe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211700(v=vs.103).aspx) override that lets you specific a `TaskScheduler` to use, so you can specify the UI scheduler so you don't have to do the marshalling yourself.

As I said in my comment, there are tons of ways to do this, so you'll have to play around to find something that fits your needs the best, but hopefully this gives you some direction.

**UPDATE**

So here's a bit of an update to your `AppCache` code (from your edit), but your question is basically that you want to get rid of the mediator and replace it with RX.  In the end, you still end up with a mediator of some sort, you just have to decide whether RX gives you something more than your own implementation of a mediate would.  *I* would (and do) use RX, but it's really a preference thing, so you're going to have to do some research on your own.

This shows you the use of the [`Observable.FromEventPattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211803%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) function, which is pretty useful and gives you a nice shortcut:

```
public static class AppCache
{

    ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    public static IObservable<ObservableCollection<MyObject>> MyObjectsObservable { get; private set; }

    private static async void GetMyObjectsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => GetMyObjects());

        NotifyMyObjectChanged() // this basically just replaces the mediator
    }

    private static GetMyObjects()
    {                   
        ...         
        MyObjects = result;
        MyObjectsObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern(h=>MyObjects.CollectionChanged += h, h=>MyObjects.CollectionChanged -= h);
    }

    static AppCache()
    {
        GetMyObjectsAsync();
    }    

}
```

I wanted to show you the usuage but this code isn't perfect, if a subscriber calls Subscribe before the `MyObjectsObservable` is created, obviously it would blow up.

Here's another link that shows you a lot of the stuff that RX can do, that to me makes it a great tool: http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#

Comment: On thing to note here is that the `.Where(x => x == value)` might not work unless you override the `Equals` method as it would fall back to reference comparisons.  Usually I would use something like `Where(x=>x.Id == value.Id)` but I don't know your object models.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CodingGorilla. How do I add values to `MyObjectsObservable` using this technique if it has no setter? Do I use the Publish() method? I am sorry if this question seems basic but I am only a 1 day old in the rx world. (And yes I do use Id's on my objects the way you do)

Comment: @AleksandrAlbert See my updates, it's a more complete example of how to implement the `IObservable`.  I use `Subject<T>`, which is a "short cut" to implementing it, and is not always the most efficient thing to use, but again its a good place to start. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211700(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Thanks I will look at this in more depth and see if it is the way for me to go, you have given me a good start

Comment: I was able to implement this as shown in my edited question, but this raises a new question raised in the edit, could you take a look at it?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will spend some more time looking at the other uses of RX to see if it makes sense bringing in the whole library to do something my small helper class does. I feel as though I would be more 'future proof' using RX, but I also like to reduce the need for external dependencies where possible.